# An unhandled exception error c#

Tags: c#, class, object, exception, unhandled

This is so confusing...
I have a class with set and get methods here is a few of them:

```
public string Naziv
    {
        get { return naziv; }
        set
        {
            naziv = value;
            if (naziv == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("Morate uneti naziv radnog mesta.");
            }
            else if (naziv.Length < 5)
            {
                throw new Exception("Naziv mora biti duzi od 5 karaktera.");
            }

        }
    }
```

This one works perfect. But this one:

```
public string RadnoVreme1
    {
        get { return radnovreme1; }
        set
        {
            radnovreme1 = value;
            if (IsValid(radnovreme1) == false)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("1:FALSE ");
                throw new Exception("Radno vreme mora biti u formatu '12:00h-20:00h'.");

            }
        }
    }
    static bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^\d{2}:\d{2}h-\d{2}:\d{2}h");
    }
```

Breaks my solution with an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Evidencija.exe Additional information: Radno vreme mora biti u formatu
>   '12:00h-20:00h'.

Another thing. When un-commenting '`Console.WriteLine`' line and commenting out '`throw new Exception`' one I get this output:

```
1:FALSE
1:FALSE 
1:FALSE 
The thread 0x1748 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Why is this running 3 times? Is it because I already have 3 stored objects in my DB? Shouldn't this only be running when creating new object?

Comment: Seems like you set RadnoVreme1 4 times somewhere. Have tried stepping through your code using breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

It's not breaking your solution, it's throwing the exception you tell it to throw which doesn't get caught by anything else in your code.  In the first example, apparently neither conditional case is being hit so no exception is thrown and your program continues executing.  If you are setting the property RadnoVreme1 multiple times elsewhere in your code you will see multiple lines of output such as you describe.  The reason the last one exits is because the condition is hit (`IsValid(radnovreme1) == false`) which throws the exception.  In the other three calls that condition does not get hit.